# Automatically Send Wallet Balance to Another Wallet

Tags: api, bitcoin, blockchain

I want to use Blockchain Wallet API : https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api to send all the bitcoins to a particular address automatically.

Like if address1 gets a deposit, it should automatically move to address2.
Any idea how will it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you are still interested in this question but I will answer anyway.

You can write a simple program that checks the balance on an adress every second / minute / hour and, if the balance is > 0, you send the balance from that particular adress to your target adress.

From the link you posted:

> **Getting the balance of an address**
>
> Retrieve the balance of a bitcoin address. Querying the balance of an
>   address by label is depreciated.
>
> http://localhost:3000/merchant/$guid/address_balance?password=$main_password&address=$address&confirmations=$confirmations
>
> ```
> $main_password Your Main Blockchain wallet password
> $address The bitcoin address to lookup
> $confirmations Minimum number of confirmations required. 0 for unconfirmed.
> ```

This is the method you call in an interval of your choice. You will get an answer in JSON-Format:

```
{"balance" : 50000000, "address" : "19r7jAbPDtfTKQ9VJpvDzFFxCjUJFKesVZ", "total_received" : 100000000}
```

If `balance` > 0, you call this method:

> **Making Outgoing Payments**
>
> Send bitcoin from your wallet to another bitcoin address. All
>   transactions include a 0.0001 BTC miners fee.
>
> All bitcoin values are in Satoshi i.e. divide by 100000000 to get the
>   amount in BTC. The Base URL for all requests:
>   https://blockchain.info/merchant/$guid/. $guid should be replaced with
>   your Blockchain Wallet identifier (found on the login page).
>
> http://localhost:3000/merchant/$guid/payment?password=$main_password&second_password=$second_password&to=$address&amount=$amount&from=$from&fee=$fee&note=$note
>
> - $main_password Your Main Blockchain Wallet password
> - $second_password Your second Blockchain Wallet password if double encryption is enabled.
> - $to Recipient Bitcoin Address.
> - $amount Amount to send in satoshi.
> - $from Send from a specific Bitcoin Address (Optional)
> - $fee Transaction fee value in satoshi (Must be greater than default    fee) (Optional)
> - $note A public note to include with the transaction -- can only be    attached when outputs are greater than 0.005 BTC. (Optional)

You can also check multiple adresses for positive balance and send it to your target adress.